# Can I make a pull request after a git clone?

Tags: git, github, git-pull, pull-request, git-fork

Do I have to fork a repo in order to make a pull request? Below is my current understanding of the repo sharing and updating process:

1. I fork a shared repo on GitHub which makes my own repo on GitHub
2. I clone from my own repo on GitHub, which gives me a local repo
3. I make a new branch "test" on local repo (which I believe will make a test branch on my remote repo on GitHub too?)
4. I make changes to working directory, add, commit, and push to remote
5. I go back onto GitHub to my repo and then make a pull request through the GUI on GitHub.

Instead of the above, is there anyway I can just clone from the shared repo and make a pull request straight from the terminal? Or do I have to go through forking and going through GitHub's GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have write access to the shared repo, then yes: you need a fork to create a pull request on GitHub. Otherwise, you won't have anywhere to push your local changes to.

> If you **do** have write access to the shared repo, you can just make a branch.

You may want to install [hub](http://hub.github.com/), a command-line GitHub tool. Then you can follow this shorter flow:

```
$ hub clone someorg/somerepo
$ cd somerepo

$ git checkout -b somefeaturebranch
…
$ git commit -am "commit message"

$ hub fork

$ git push YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME somefeaturebranch
$ hub pull-request
```

Once configured, you can actually use `git` and `hub` interchangeably. I just kept them separate so you could see which were Git commands and which were GitHub commands.

Comment: so here it's ok to fork after you've made changes? does that fork's remote repo copy the origin's and then your push updates that fork's remote? then the pull-request will use that updated remote to make a request? is this is what it's doing, isn't it just the same thing as not having write access?

Comment: Sure, you can fork before or after making changes on a branch. Doesn't matter. All that matters is you push your changes in a branch to your fork, then open a PR from the fork to the main repo.

Comment: In fact, if you are regularly contributing somewhere, you can just make the fork once and keep it around.

Comment: how is this different if you have write access or not?

Comment: If you have write access you can just push your branch to the same repo you cloned from

Comment: You might like this code school course, which compares both workflows and also covers `hub`: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/mastering-github